# JBoss 5.1.2 provided libraries besides Java EE 5 spec as Maven artifacts

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jboss5.x

Is there a way to easily add all (or most) useful JBoss 5.1.2 provided libraries API-s that are out of Java EE 5 spec?

For example: I know that JBoss provides me a possibility of using Log4J logging but I don't know what to put as a `provided` artifact to my maven project. I guess it is jboss-logging-something. I want it to provide me a logging API only.

Is there a list of maven artifacts for APIs that JBoss AS 5 provides (besides Java EE 5 spec)?

*EDIT*

It seems that adding this dependency is quite helpful:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb3</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

But it causes maven load pretty whole Jboss AS server code. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think a better idea is to use the libraries provided by the JBOSS server you deploy on and not have those in your package.  Link to the necessary libraries for compiling and running, but don't add them to your spec.

JBOSS has libraries in its `/lib`, `deploy/lib`, and the `endorsed/lib` folders.

Comment: That is what I want to do. I want to put those libs as `provided` dependencies and not to package them. The qestion is `what I need to put` and wich versions?

Comment: You don't need to put them anywhere; they're already part of the JBOSS you're deploying to.  Just point to them.  And the versions are the ones that are already in JBOSS.  I don't see a role for Maven.

Comment: The role of Maven is "Just point to them". What is more this will give me all libraries,both APIs an internal implementation.

Comment: And there is a common/lib. Should I add this too? The problem is that I cannot distinguish internal libs from end user libs that I should add to my classpath.

Comment: All the ones that are pertinent, of course.  They should be orthogonal.  Server and user libs don't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

The following quote is from the [Installation Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Installation_And_Getting_Started_Guide/5/html_single/index.html#Whatsnew_Component_Upgrades)

*For a full list of the JBoss and thirdparty libraries used with JBoss AS 5.0.0.GA check the pom.xml found in the component-matrix directory of the source code distribution. To see the maven dependency tree you can run 'mvn dependency:tree' from the thirdparty directory of the source code distro.*

You can download the source from here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/JBoss/JBoss-5.1.0.GA/

and then checkout the pom as described above. Be warned it is a long list, but should provide you with the information that you are looking for.

Comment: Yes. I've seen it. It seems that this provides both APIs and implementations. This unfortunatelly seems to be the closest answer.